# $eq invalid syntax Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a nested json and i want to find a record whose value is equal to a given number. I'm using pymongo in python wih equal operator but  getting some errors:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import json
import pprint
def connectDatabase(service):
    try:
        if service=="mongodb":
            host = 'mongodb://connecion_string.mlab.com:31989'
            database = 'xxx'
            user = 'xxx'
            password = 'xxx'
            client = MongoClient(host)
            client.xxx.authenticate(user, password, mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
            db = client.xxx
            new_posts = [{"author": "Mike", "text": "Another post!",
               "tags": [
               {
                "CSPAccountNo": "414693"
                },
               {
               "CSPAccountNo": "349903"
               }]
               }]
               result=db.posts1.insert_many(new_posts)

            print (xxx.posts1.find( {"CSPAccountNo": { $eq: "414693" } } )

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
print (connectDatabase("mongodb"))
```

Error:

```
  File "mongo.py", line 35
    print (cstore.posts1.find( {"CSPAccountNo": { $eq: "414693" } } )
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm very new to Mongodb. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you have to use Python syntax, not JS syntax like in the Mongo shell. That means that dictionary keys need quotes:

```
print(cstore.posts1.find( {"CSPAccountNo": { "$eq": "414693" } } )
```

(Note, in your code you never actually insert the `new_posts` into the collection, so your find call might not actually find anything.)

Comment: Yes i missed the code there an added it again. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
print (xxx.posts1.find( {"tags.CSPAccountNo": { $eq: "414693" } } )
```

Comment: Still the same error. I doubt whether pymongo allows this functionality like mongo db shell?